# Encontrar caractere na string

Tags: php

Como encontrar a posição de uma determinado caractere, sendo que a string possui muitos destes caracteres na mesma string, exemplo: encontrar a 3ª letra X na string Y. alguma forma de realizar isto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso pede uma função especializada. Bem, desenvolvi rapidamente a seguinte:

```
function nthstrpos($haystack, $needle, $nth) {
    $count = 0;
    $pos = -1;
    do {
        $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle, $pos + 1);
        $count++;
    } while ($pos !== false && $count < $nth);
    return $pos;
}
```

A função `nthstrpos()` recebe três parâmetros:

1. Texto a ser pesquisado (palheiro)
2. Texto a ser procurado (agulha)
3. Número da ocorrência a ser localizada (n-ésima ocorrência do parâmetro anterior), sendo `1` a primeira ocorrência e assim por diante

Por exemplo, o comando `nthstrpos('banana', 'a', 2)` vai retornar a segunda ocorrência da letra `a` no texto `banana`.

Caso o texto a ser procurado não seja encontrado ou o número da ocorrência solicitada exceda o total de ocorrências existentes o retorno será `false`.

#### [Execute no Ideone](http://ideone.com/d1Xwey)

Comment: Funciona perfeitamente, Obrigado

Answer (score 4):

usa strpos http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php

sendo que vc pode fazer um loop passando o $offset de onde a função deve começar a buscar

---

Algo assim

```
<?php

$texto = "um texto muito longo cheio de letras, numeros, fatos, historias, aventuras e altas confusões na sessao da tarde.";
$achar = "a";
$posicoes = array();
$offset = 0;

while ( ($pos = strpos($texto, $achar, $offset)) !== false) {

    $posicoes[] = $pos;
    $offset = $pos+1;
}

print_r($posicoes);
```

---

Update

se você quiser também pode usar expressões regulares, o que na minha opinião é bem mais elegante:

```
<?php

$re = "/a/";
$str = "um texto muito longo cheio de letras, numeros, fatos, historias, aventuras e altas confusões na sessao da tarde.";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $resultados, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

print_r($resultados);
```

Comment: mas como poderia encontrar a 3ª letra X na string Y, sendo que não sei a quantidade e nem a posição da letra X na String?

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a função [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos). Seus parâmetros são:

- `$haystack`: A *string* na qual será feita a busca.
- `$needle`: Caracteres a serem buscados.
- `$offset`: Esse parâmetro permite definir a partir de qual caractere em `$haystack` iniciar a busca.

Podemos usar este último parâmetro para fazer esse tipo de busca, assim:

```php
function strposNth($texto, $procurar, $n){
    switch($n){
        case $n === 0:
            return false;
            break;
        case $n === 1:
            return(strpos($texto, $encontrar) + 1);
            break;
        default:
            return(strpos($texto, $procurar, strposNth($texto, $procurar, $n - 1) +
            strlen($procurar)) + 1);
            break;
    }
}
```

Para usá-la:

```
echo strposNth("overflow", "o", 2); // 7
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/2dGtj5)</kbd>

Comment: mas como poderia encontrar a 3ª letra X na string Y, sendo que não sei a quantidade e nem a posição da letra X na String?

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Melhorei a resposta.

Answer (score -1):

```
$test = "Hi, How are you!";

function strCharFind($needle,$haystack){
    $return = FALSE;
    $arr = str_split($haystack,1);
    foreach($arr as $value){
        if($value==strtolower($needle)||$value==strtoupper($needle)){
            $return = TRUE;
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

var_dump(strCharFind(',',$test));//true
var_dump(strCharFind('h',$test));//true
var_dump(strCharFind('!',$test));//true
var_dump(strCharFind('?',$test));//false
```

Comment: Saudações, Andre. É legal que queira contribuir com a comunidade, mas seria interessante você adicionar explicações à sua resposta. Um código que pode ser trivial para você pode não ser para os outros usuários, então busque sempre explicar por texto a lógica implementada.